# matching error with my XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm getting crazy. I only want to retrieve few values in my xml :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
  <SearchDocumentResponse xmlns="http://axa.fr/gedald/2010/11">
     <SearchDocumentResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <DocumentCollection>
           <document>
              <ObjectStore i:nil="true"/>
              <DocId>{1DC43D04-2541-459C-83A7-BA6A761C64B5}</DocId>
              <IndexCollection>
                 <index>
                    <IndexId>P001</IndexId>
                    <Value>OBJ002301</Value>
                 </index>
                 <index>
                    <IndexId>P002</IndexId>
                    <Value>15/11/2013 13:00:00</Value>
                 </index>
              </IndexCollection>
           </document>
        </DocumentCollection>
        <Message i:nil="true"/>
        <NbDocument>7</NbDocument>
        <Result>OK</Result>
     </SearchDocumentResult>
  </SearchDocumentResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Whatever I try as an XSL file, I can't get to the content. Sometimes I get every tag content. But never what I want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="s:Envelope/s:Body/SearchDocumentResponse/SearchDocumentResult/DocumentCollection/document/IndexCollection">
   <html>
     <body>
       <xsl:value-of select="DocId"/>
       <xsl:for-each select="index">
          <ul>
            <li><xsl:value-of select="IndexId"/></li>
            <li><xsl:value-of select="Value"/></li>
          </ul>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements in your source document are in various namespaces, so you need to bind the same namespace URIs to suitable prefixes in your stylesheet, and then use those prefixes in your XPath expressions:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:axa="http://axa.fr/gedald/2010/11">

  <xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
     <body>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="s:Envelope/s:Body/axa:SearchDocumentResponse/axa:SearchDocumentResult/axa:DocumentCollection/axa:document/axa:IndexCollection" />
     </body>
   </html>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="axa:IndexCollection">
     <xsl:value-of select="axa:DocId"/>
     <xsl:for-each select="axa:index">
        <ul>
          <li><xsl:value-of select="axa:IndexId"/></li>
          <li><xsl:value-of select="axa:Value"/></li>
        </ul>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unprefixed names in XPath 1.0 expressions always refer to nodes that are not in a namespace, which is why things like `DocId` do not select anything.

Comment: Perfect. But I still don't understand how it is working... why do I have ot put axa before SearchDocumentResponse whereas it is not in the XML ?

Comment: @TDLemon because that's the way XML namespaces work - the `xmlns="http://axa.fr/gedald/2010/11"` in the XML puts that element and all its descendant elements with un-prefixed names into the `http://axa.fr/gedald/2010/11` namespace.  To match namespaced nodes in XPath 1.0 you _must_ use prefixes.

Comment: @TDLemon XSLT/XPath doesn't care what prefixes or default namespace declarations the original XML document uses, what matters is that you declare prefix bindings _in the stylesheet_ for the right namespace URIs and then use those prefixes consistently.  I could have used `xmlns:blah="http://axa.fr/gedald/2010/11"` and `blah:SearchDocumentResponse` and that would have worked equally well.